Alphabetizing in amsrefs
I am working with pdfLatex, and using \usepackage[nobysame, alphabetic]{amsrefs} in the preamble with \bibliographystyle{abbrv} and \bibliography{references} at the end of the document.  I noticed that AMSREFS is not totally alphabetizing the authors, in the sense that I am referencing a paper published by a single author last name Aston, and then I am citing a paper with multiple authors, the first of which has last name Aaronson, but in the bibliography the "Aston" paper appears right before the "Aaronson" paper.  Is there a way to force AMSRefs to give a more "total" alphabetization so that Aaronson appears first?
More code: the preamble,
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsaddr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[nobysame, alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}

and the relevant portion of the references.bib file, in this order in the file.
@ARTICLE{Aaronson,
   author    = "G. Aaronson and A. Hill and Ya. Mason",
   title     = "Periodic dynamics",
   journal   = "Journal of x",
   volume    = 47,
   year      = 1992,
   pages     = "5--80",
}

@ARTICLE{Aston,
   author    = "A. Aston",
   title     = "Dynamics of",
   journal   = "Journal of x",
   volume    = 44,
   year      = 2000,
   pages     = "465--478",
}


Can you please show a short example of code?

On p.17 of the amsrefs documentation, there is a prominent note that says the order of the entries is left up to the user.  The alphabetic key refers to the construction of the label.

@egreg yes I edited the question with more details

@barbarabeeton Can you describe what you mean? Is there some way I can force ordering in the .bib file?

@barbarabeeton I have referred to the page of the documentation you mention and I do not see any indication as to how to forcibly order these bilbliography entries

I checked the user guide on CTAN.  It clearly says that the user is responsible for putting the entries in the desired order.  So if you want them in alphabetical order, they will have to the entered in your file in that order.  There isn't any mechanism for doing that automatically.

Using amsrefs with BibTeX is possible, but not recommended. The idea is that you can use a BibTeX database, but then you should include the generated bibdiv environment in the document after checking it for sorting and general shape.
Anyway, the following code
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Aaronson,
   author    = "G. Aaronson and A. Hill and Ya. Mason",
   title     = "Periodic dynamics",
   journal   = "Journal of x",
   volume    = 47,
   year      = 1992,
   pages     = "5--80",
}
@ARTICLE{Aston,
   author    = "A. Aston",
   title     = "Dynamics of",
   journal   = "Journal of x",
   volume    = 44,
   year      = 2000,
   pages     = "465--478",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[nobysame, alphabetic]{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

\cite{Aston}

\cite{Aaronson}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}

where filecontents* is only used for making the example self-contained, produces the correct order.

As a favor to yourself and your readers, please use a numeric format. Abbreviation styles were common when scientific papers were typewritten and it was impossible to know in advance the citations. Similarly for ordering by appearance. With a computer, numbering and sorting is easy and makes the bibliography easier to browse.
